# Is there a way to select the first instance of a duplicated file in dupeguru?

Tags: deduplication

dupeguru has helped me find duplicated files, but it only allows me to delete the second instance of duplicated files (as shown in the screenshot). I wonder if there's a way to delete the first instance?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The folders marked in blue which you are saying you want to delete are what dupeGuru calls 'Reference' folders, these cannot be deleted which is why you cannot select them. In this way dupeGuru allows you to set your 'important' folders than you don't want to delete any duplicates from.

If you do wish to delete files from those blue-marked folders you will need to go back to the start of the dupeGuru search process, and change the 'state' of those folders to 'Normal' in the Folder List. After you run a search for duplicates again they will then be able to be selected as duplicates for deletion.

Reference and more info: https://dupeguru.voltaicideas.net/help/en/folders.html

Comment: The state is already selected as Normal, but blue-marked folders are still not selectable

Answer (score 0):

The following excerpt from the dupeguru documentation might have the
solution.

> [**I want to make my latest modified files reference files. What can I
> do?**](https://dupeguru.voltaicideas.net/help/en/faq.html#i-want-to-make-my-latest-modified-files-reference-files-what-can-i-do)
>
> - Enable the [Dupes Only](https://dupeguru.voltaicideas.net/help/en/results.html) mode.
> - Enable the **Delta Values** mode.
> - Click on the “Modification” column to sort the results by modification date.
> - Click on the “Modification” column again to reverse the sort order.
> - Select all duplicates over 0.
> - Click on **Make Selected into Reference**.